# Select the child node in Oracle xmltype

Tags: oracle, xmltype

Requirement is to display the Contact details stored in xmlformat.
My dataset as below:

```
Id   XMldata
123  "<row id="123"><c1>Home</c1><c1 m="2">Office</c1><c1 M="3">Personal</c1><c2>+91</c2><c2 m="2">+65</c2><c2 m="3">+1</c2><c3>9900990090</c3><c3 m="2">55667788</c3><c3 m="3">123789073</c3><c4>Test element</c4></row>"
```

I need to build a select query to select child node matching Office contact details and to view the output in the below format:

```
Id  C1     C2  C3 
123 Office +65 55667788
```

Comment: Why 200 and Y? The 200 could maybe be from matching `m` attribute; but then `c3` shoudl be N?

Comment: This makes no sense.  please clarify

Comment: C1, C2 & C3 are assiociated set, but stored in different column. C3 should be Y and some cases its updates as Null instead of N as both represents the same functionality in the application. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: But *how* are they associated? How do you know which C1 goes with which C2 and C3 - when you look at the data manually, to start with? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62429338/edit) to explain the logic you're applying.

Comment: I have amended the xml data to display the customer phone details which will make more sense on the associated data set. Where c1 - refers to phone no classification (Office, Personal,work,etc..) , c2 - refers to Country code and C3 - will be the mobile or landline no.